# Prove $\Gamma^k_{ij,l} + \Gamma^k_{jl,i} +\Gamma^k_{li,j} = 0$ at $p$ inside the normal coordinate

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M,g)$ be the Riemannian manifold, Prove inside the normal coordiante around $p$ we have following $$\Gamma^k_{ij,l} + \Gamma^k_{jl,i} +\Gamma^k_{li,j} = 0 \tag{*}
$$ at $p$, where $\Gamma^k_{ij,l} = \frac{\partial \Gamma_{ij}^k}{\partial x_l}
$.

I have no idea how to prove this, therefore I have to use the definition $$\nabla_{\partial_l} (\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j) = \Gamma^{k}_{ij,l} \partial_k$$ at $p$,where we use the fact $\nabla_{\partial_l}\partial_j = 0$ at $p$. Therefore:$$g(\nabla_{\partial_l}(\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j), \partial_k) = \Gamma^k_{ij,l}$$ at $p$, one of term in (*) appears .Hence is equivalent to prove that
$$\nabla_{\partial_l }\nabla_{\partial_{i}}\partial_j + \nabla_{\partial_i}\nabla_{\partial_j }\partial_l + \nabla_{\partial_j}\nabla_{\partial_l}\partial_i =0$$ at $p$.I'm not sure is my proof idea possible to get the result? Or is there some better idea?

Comment: Let $\gamma = t(c^1,...,c^n)$ be the geodesic inside the normal coordinate hence $$D_t(c^i\partial_i)  = c^ic^j\Gamma_{ij}^k =0$$

Hence if we take $D_t$ again $$c^ic^jc^l\Gamma^k_{ij,l} =0$$ for any chooice of $c = (c^1,...,c^n)$

Comment: If we choose $c$ properly,will gets the solution.

Comment: No. You have to use the fact that it holds for all $c$. Multiply the left side of (*) by $c^ic^jc^k$, sum over all $i,j,k$ and simplify.

Comment: yeah, if we take $c = e_{i_0} + e_{j_0} + e_{l_0}$ then we only get $$\sum_{(i,j,l) \in \{i_0,j_0,l_0\}^3} \Gamma^{k}_{ij,l} = 0$$

Comment: If we take $c = e_k$ , for $k = i_0,j_0,l_0$ then we eliminate three terms  that $ i = j = l$ above, if we take $c = e_a+ a_b$ for ${(a,b)} \in \{i_0,j_0,k_0\}^2$ we eliminate six terms that $i = j$ or $j = l$ or $i = l$ so only three terms we want left

Comment: Observe that $$\sum A_{ijk}x^ix^jx^k = \sum_{ijk} \frac{1}{3}(A_{ijk}+A_{jki}+A_{kij})x^ix^jx^k$$

Comment: Replace $x^i$ by $c^i$ and $A_{ijk}$ by $\Gamma^l_{ij,k}$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see why $\sum A_{ijk}x^ix^jx^k = \sum_{ijk} \frac{1}{3}(A_{ijk}+A_{jki}+A_{kij})x^ix^jx^k
$ implies $A_{ijk}+ A_{jki}+ A_{kij} = 0$,except substitute specific $x$ into it? @Deane

Comment: This looks quite like a three-linear form. If we look at the bilinear form $<x,Ax> = 0$ for all $x$ then it implies $A$ is anti-symmetric,here we just generalize it to three-linear form

Comment: A homogeneous polynomial is identically zero if and only if its coefficients are all zero. Here, you have a homogeneous polynomrial $P(c^1, \dots, c^n)$ of degree $3$. Since it is identically zero, its coefficients (with the indices symmetrized) are all zero.

Comment: Yeah I see $B(x,y,z) = \sum_{ijk} \frac{1}{3}(A_{ijk}+A_{jki}+A_{kij})x^iy^jz^k
$ defines a symmetric multilinear map, we can use the polarlization trick combined with the fact $B(x,x,x) = 0$ to deduce that $B = 0$ @Deane

Comment: A homogeneous cubic polynomial in say two variables looks like $p(c^1,c^2) = \alpha (c^1)^3 + \beta( c^1)^2c^2 + \gamma c_1(c_2)^2 + \delta (c_2)^3$. This polynomial is zero if and only if its coefficients $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ are all zero. I don't think any trick is needed.

Comment: I look at this trick in Nicolaescu's differential geometry book, when he introduce the invariant polynomial , which says every symmetric multilinear map is associated to a polynomial and the polynomial is constant zero here so the multilinear map is zero.@Deane

Comment: But you don’t need the trick, since you already wrote it as a polynomial